# Astra starter site import not getting through, it pops 'not found' and forever keep the importing site going on

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just started building my website using wordpress.org application installed/ supported by Hostinger.

I am facing a problem with importing the "Astra starter site".

So first I added a new theme - Astra then applied it, later as per the guided tutorial, I added the plugin "Astra starter site" after it was loaded, I activated it and then I went to appearance in the that I clicked on Astra starter sites and from the free ready sites, I selected the "outbound Adventure", after landing on the page, I had to import site by accepting the import of support 'plugins, widgets, content and customizer settings'.. after I clicked on import sites, it showed that the process would take anywhere between 2 to 10 mins, however, it never got completed and my site was never loaded.. (I tried using other free site but the problem persists) I am attaching a screen shot which would possibly explain the error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAKgh.png)

Please help get through this..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the execution time limit: Refer document link below

You can change it using : https://wpastra.com/docs/increase-php-time-limit-wordpress-sites/